# Why aren't my audio devices recognized?

Tags: fedora, linux-mint, audio, devices

On my laptop, only Dummy Output appears in Sound Preferences. This is Mint 20.3, but similarly, nothing is found  when running on with an Endeavor or Fedora live-USB-stick. Headphones in the AUX do not work either. With Windows, audio works.  Apparently the sound card is HDA Intel PCH (see `aplay -l` below).  `arecord --list-devices` gives an empty result (below). See also `arecord --list-pcms` and `/sbin/lsmod | grep snd` below.

How can I get this working?

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
arecord --list-devices


**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
```

```
$ arecord --list-pcms
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
surround21
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
usbstream:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH
    USB Stream Output
```

```
$ /sbin/lsmod | grep snd
snd_sof_pci            20480  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    73728  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      20480  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               106496  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    32768  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_sof
snd_soc_core          249856  3 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_intel          53248  1
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         139264  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           90112  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    90112  13 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

Answer (score 0):

What you think is the sound card supplying your speakers and headphone plug is likely not: you'll notice all of these have `[HDMI]` in their name. That's because they're the different interfaces with which you can deliver audio over HDMI to an external screen with a speaker!

So, since I guess no such screen is plugged in, you don't get to choose one of these from your session.

Your analog soundcard is not listed there. If it is really handled by the Intel PCH (don't know whether that is a thing, it's not the case on my laptop), then that would mean it's somehow disabled.

More likely is that you've got another device acting as the analog soundcard that for some reason doesn't work. Check `lspci` and `lsusb` for things that look like soundcards, and try to figure out whether their supplier (or a volunteer?) put in the work to write a Linux driver just as they wrote a Windows driver. You can also use the Device Manager under Windows to figure out what your actual sound hardware is!